# Calling a webservice on remote machine with JQuery/JavaScript without changing webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I have a webservice running on my server, but i don't have the code to modify it, i can only make changes in its config file.

I'm in need to call this webservice from JQuery/JavaScript.

This is what i tried so far

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{null}",
            url: "http://example.com:1032/service1.asmx/HelloWorld",
            dataTyp: "json",
            success: function (res) {
                debugger;
                $("#Text1").val(res.text);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                debugger;
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But no success, it goes in error block.
I also tried this url in browser`http://example.com:1032/service1.asmx/HelloWorld` from other machine but it says `The test form is only available for requests from the local machine.`

I have gone through related questions but they require change in webservice.

**Is there anyway i can call service without changing code for webservice?**

**EDIT:** Error i get in jquery

```
err = Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<html>
↵ <head>
↵ <title>Runtime Error</…le>
↵
↵ <br>
↵
↵ </body>
↵</html>
↵", status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}
```

**EDIT:** Just to add, I'm able to call this service method from C# ASP.Net site running on other machine

Comment: Could you provide the exact error message?

Comment: Error message i receive in jquery ?

Comment: I presume you can call this service from the machine the service is installed om? If yes, then you will need to set up a proxy on the server to make requests locally on behalf of your remote clients.

Comment: Any directions how can i do that?

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh so it's an internal server error. Might  be something wrong with your data. I think `data: "{null}"` is not correct json, cause objects contain name/value pairs separated by commas. If you want to provide an empty object just use `data: {}` or `data: "{}"`.

Comment: @sfrutig No luck, giving same error

Comment: So difficult to say what's wrong. Would be ideal if you also could provide the exception stack trace from the server. There are 2 other misspellings I saw: `contenttype` instead of `contentType` and `dataTyp` instead of `dataType`.

Comment: When i change them i get error, and now after adding changes in web.config (below answered) its working with above exact code. thanks for your efforts though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, Adding this to my config worked for me

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
     <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I can now call service from browser and jquery as well, with above method, from remote machine